# Strange float behaviour in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I want to create a simple box with a header bar containing a title and some tool buttons. I have the following markup:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div style="background-color:blue; padding: 1px; height: 20px;">
        <div style="float: left; background-color:green;">title</div>
        <div style="float: right; background-color:yellow;">toolbar</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; width: 200px; background-color: red;">content</div>
</div>
```

This renders fine in Firefox and Chrome:

http://www.boplicity.nl/images/firefox.jpg

However IE7 totally messes up and puts the right floated element to the right of the page:

http://www.boplicity.nl/images/ie7.jpg

Can this be fixed?

Comment: You might need to give a bit more context for this question. you were saying that content area will contain tables of varying size?

Comment: Useful http://css-class.com/articles/explorer/floats/floatandcleartest1.htm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Specify width in outermost div. 
If that width in your content div means this is the total width of your box, simply add it to the outermost div, and (optionally) remove it from content, like this:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 200px;">
    <div style="background-color:blue; padding: 1px; height: 20px;">
        <div style="float: left; background-color:green;">title</div>
        <div style="float: right; background-color:yellow;">toolbar</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; background-color: red;">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixes it. However the content size may not be known up front. On my site it usually contains tables whose width can grow.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a quick answer, so I hold my hands up if it doesn't quite work. I think Marko's solution will probably work if you just add min-width rather than width. If you are trying to cater for ie6 as well, you may need to use a hack, as min width is not supported by ie6 and it's descendants.

So this should work with IE7 and other modern browers. Set the min-width to whatever is appropriate.

```
<div style="float:left; min-width: 200px;">
    <div style="background-color:blue; padding: 1px; height: 20px;">
        <div style="float: left; background-color:green;">title</div>
        <div style="float: right; background-color:yellow;">toolbar</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; background-color: red;">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, min-width has no effect in this case

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using jQuery to emulate the behaviour of the non-IE browsers:

```
    // IE fix for div widths - size header to width of content
    if (!$.support.cssFloat) {
        $("div:has(.boxheader) > table").each(function () {
                $(this).parent().width($(this).width());
        });
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: It fixes the problem. Instead of setting widths statically like other posters suggested I now set it dynamically.

Comment: Throwing a 50K javascript library at this is not the best solution when a CSS hack can fix this.

Comment: I was already using jQuery in my app so that was not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `position:relative;` to parent-element and to the child-element. It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got to know recently that the right floated elements need to be appended with the divs before the other elements. This is the easiest fix without adding a line of change.

```
<div style="background-color:blue; padding: 1px; height: 20px;">
    <div style="float: right; background-color:green;">title</div>
    <div style="float: left; background-color:yellow;">toolbar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is true, however, the important difference here is that your outer `div` is not floated. If you float that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Make this `<div style="background-color:blue; padding: 1px; height: 20px;>` the parent of the 2 floating divs also `clear:all`

Comment: Sorry, that did not help.

Here are the screenshots: www.boplicity.nl/images/firefox.jpg www.boplicity.nl/images/ie7.jpg