# Scroll Bar Forcing Div Down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs in a content container one floating left and the other floating right. I am using the whole width of the screen. Left div width is 1290px and right div width is 625px. Sometimes when loading the page the scroll bar is changing the width of the available screen width and causing the div that floats right to get caught under the div that floats left. This happens after I added a footer div. I don't want to make the two divs a smaller width because this is for an ad display in clients offices. I need the full screen. Thanks!

Comment: I would agree with Diodues' suggestion.  However, if you need it to look correct on Internet Explorer 7 (curses on that blasted browser), you may run into issues.  Often times, when I have multiple divs floated left, IE7 renders awful.  If you don't have to worry bout IE7, I would agree with floating them both left.

This may also help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187279/strange-float-behaviour-in-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to switch from floats to absolutes wrapped in a relative container?

Something like this (I shortened the widths for the sake of the sample...):
http://jsfiddle.net/perrytew/E6dUj/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style type='text/css'>
    #container{
    /* width: 1915px; */
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.leftpane {
    /* width: 1290px; */
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.rightpane {
    /* width: 625px; */
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* left: 1290px; */
    left: 100px;
}       
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='#container'>
        <div class='leftpane'>Left Content</div>
        <div class='rightpane'>Right Content</div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```