# IE7 Stacking left floated divs in jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, internet-explorer-7

I'm messing around with a content slider for a template I downloaded. I've got it pretty much how I want in all the modern browsers.  Now I'm trying some cross browser testing and I've come across a bug in ie7 where it is stacking the items instead of floating them across the screen and hiding them.

Here's my site:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62054561/Rust%20Website/index.html

But here's how it looks in IE7:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62054561/ie7.png]

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: yep, all the other plugins are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 errors in your Javascript.

You're trying to multiply a string by a number, which is causing it to break:

> ```
> var height = '190',
>     width = '915',
>     slides = 3,
>     tabs = $('.tab'),
>     contentNum = 1;
> ```

You're also missing the quotes around `'width'` in your jquery `.css()` function

> ```
> $('.slider_main_inner').css({
>     width: slides * width,
> });
> ```

## Fixed Version

Use numbers instead of strings, and add the quotes around `width`

> ```
> var height = 190,
>     width = 915,
>     slides = 3,
>     tabs = $('.tab'),
>     contentNum = 1;
>
> $('.slider_main_inner').css({
>     'width': (slides * width)
> });
> ```

Comment: it's still not working :-( this is driving me crazy, thanks for all your help.

Comment: oops, just noticed something else. You're missing the quotes `''` in your jQuery CSS statement

it should be `$('.slider_main_inner').css({
    'width': slides * width,
});`

Comment: also there's an extra comma after `slides*width` that i've just noticed.
I've edited my answer

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!! Thank you so much for your help with this, I'm very new to code as you can probably tell.

Answer (score 1):

give the outermost div a specified width, in your case:

```
<div class="slider_main" style="width: 915px">
    ....content.....
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And so on.

I struck a similar problem not so long ago, found the answer here: [Strange float behaviour in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187279/strange-float-behaviour-in-ie7)

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmmm, that doesn't seem to be working for me.  not sure i understand the closing tag either?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with IE and inline-block elements.

Everywhere that you have the following CSS code

> ```
> display:inline-block
> ```

You need to add this for IE

> ```
>     display:inline-block;
>     *display: inline;
>     zoom:1;
> ```

Comment: i've added those to all of the inline-block elements but it still won't play! man i hate IE.  thanks for your help

Comment: did you add it to `.slider_content` ?

Comment: i built a jsfiddle before building the page to get it working which is here... http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4q3GZ/6/

does jsfiddle behave differently in Internet Explorer 7? because this works as expected...

Comment: new answer...i think i've found it. It's a Javascript problem