# IE7 (and 6) float clearing issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a list I'm trying to split into three columns by floating everything left then clearing the first.

No problem in IE8, FF etc but IE7 is kicking the second column out.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/EVMzj/3/

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187279/strange-float-behaviour-in-ie7

Comment: Setting a width doesn't seem to fix it... http://jsfiddle.net/EVMzj/4/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the CSS propierty box-sizing?

If you use `box-sizing: border-box` the box you apply this will have the width and height you applied in the styles, without problems about margins and paddings with undesirable effects on the box sizes.