# Float incorrect on internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-float

I have been creating a webpage for a real estate site.

It is hosted at this [site](http://www.cs.unca.edu/~ruggiejl/rcsqueeze/index.html)

My problem is that when viewing on IE, the second line of the right headline "Discover Your Casual Gated Community" doesn't float to the right, and rather gets stuck behind the logo on the left.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `clear: both;` to your `h1#botline` and the `p` after the `h1#botline`

Works in IE7+

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a div as container in ur code and then give the CSS float property to that div . Hope it works .
Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187279/strange-float-behaviour-in-ie7) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float: right` from the 3 elements (h1, h1, p) in the div with `id="valueprop"`, remove the `<br />` and everything lines out fine in IE (10).

Comment: I appreciate your response, however when removing the float:right from the css, the 3 lines are not aligned by the right hand side.